# Глючит плагин facebook

Tags: facebook

Вот мой код, который установлен на сайте... **** - это нормально, там подставлено все нормально.... все работало отлично, но сегодня обратил внимание, что на главной странице работает, а на остальных страницах нет.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/******" data-width="265" data-height="362" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"  data-border-color="#ffffff"></div>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=********";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>
```

Очень странно, ошибок в консоли нет, только есть предупреждения. Вот такие:

```
The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating all.js:56
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

Подскажите плиз, из-за чего это могло все испортится?

Comment: ну видимо надо дернуть сначала fb.init,


вам сюда: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

Comment: Спасибо, я поправил, но работает не так как хотел, просто этот плагин хотел кидать через секунду после загрузки страницы с помощью Ajax. Но как только вставил чисто в код сразу заработало.